# how to select rows from one table with specific id of other rows in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table like this

```
 id | `name` |  `aid`
---------------------
  1 |  sara  |   2
  2 | jack   |   2
  3 | chris  |   1
  4 | dan    |   1
  6 | sara   |   3
  7 | jules  |   3
  8 | jade   |   2
```

Now what I want to do is I want to display to sara all the people who have the same aid as her. Basically the logic here is taking the aid's of sara(2 and 3) and then putting another query where aid is 2 and 3 . How would I do this Dynamically where sara is a user with an ongoing session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE aid 
IN (
  SELECT aid 
  FROM table 
  WHERE name='sara'
) 
AND name != 'sara'
```

It uses a subquery to get the ids of sara and then compares them to others.The last part can be removed if you want to show sara in the list.

You could also get saras IDs before hand and use IN(2,3) if you want but I'm not sure if that's any better/more efficient.

Comment: Note that if there's another row with the name "sara" you will filter it even though you shouldn't , to be sure not to select the same row you should check the id and not the name.

Comment: I assumed that the name field was distinct because op says that they want the aids of sara which are 3 and 2 in this example. To do it by ID you'd have to use IDs 1 and 6

Answer (score 1):

You can self join the table:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.aid, t2.name AS matched_name
FROM myTable t1
JOIN myTable t2
ON t1.aid = t2.aid
WHERE t1.name = 'sara' 
AND t1.id != t2.id // to avoid selecting the same row
```